# What is purpose of cluster and sql server ips in FCI

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have installed 2 node FCI and 1 standalone instance, added all 3 nodes to cluster, along with file share witness, and via SSMS configured AG between the FCI and standalone instance for 1 db.

For this I had to make ips for the following:

1. Node1
2. Node2
3. Cluster (during cluster creation)
4. Sql server (during installation)
5. AG listener (during AG creation)

My understanding is that (correct me please):

1. Cluster IP to be used to automatically RDP into the active node?
2. SQL server IP to be used to automatically via SSMS (or client app) connect to the active sql fci node?
3. Listener IP to be used to connect to db and it will auto direct to primary replica by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. You can ignore cluster IP. It is the IP of the main cluster service It is not directly related to SQL Server and can be hosted by a node where Sql Server is not running.
2. This is the IP assigned to the 'moving' (FCI) SQL instance and has to be used from SSMS and application except for the AG database member.
3. This IP (the one associated to the AG listener) has to be used when you need to connect applications to the AG database members, to reach the primary.

You have other two IPs. The nodes' IPs. You can use them to connect in RDP to the single nodes (for patching or other OS duties).

- Node1 --> use it for node maintenace
- Node2 --> use it for node maintenace
- Cluster --> don't use it
- Sql server --> use for sql activities related to FCI instance (maintenace or system databases or databases not under AG)
- AG listener --> use for app interaction with db under AG
- standalone node --> use for standalone node maintenace or sql activities related to that instance (maintenace or system databases or databases not under AG)

Comment: In point 1 - what do you mean by `can be hosted by a node where Sql Server is not running`? Do you mean to say that in a 2-node FCI do I need another node for hosting the cluster IP?

Comment: No , I was simply saying that the cluster IP can be on node 1 and the sql server ip can be on node 2 (sql active node)

Comment: What does cluster IP can be on node 1 mean. Sorry for my lack of knowledge I don't get you. I thought all 4 ips (cluster, node1, node2, sqlsvr) are different and independent.

Comment: please can you comment on my above question?

Comment: Yes the are indipendent. The CLuster IP is not even related to the active node of the FCI.
you can have for example it on node1 but the FCI IP is on node 2. Then you can have AG standalone node primary and FCI node secondary for a single AG. The listener IPs can't be on a node different from the one is hosting the FCI ip except for the standalone node.

Comment: How do I decide whether to share the node 1 IP with the FCI IP or not ? Ideally it it good practice to have separate IP or share?

Comment: Don't use nodes IPs for sql activity. use them only for maintenance of each node.
Don't use IP but use FQDN names. If you want to use IPs use FCI ip for instance connectivity (to reach system databasases or databases not in AG). Use listeners IPs for specific databases connectivity in that AG. Use standalone IP for reaching standalone instance.

Comment: added a schema to the answer

Comment: So for fci ip when you say don't use, then why is it ever needed?

Comment: Isn't cluster ip to be used by end user to connect to the active node in the fci?

Comment: FCI has it own IP. CLuster IP is another one. Use FCI IP for connecting to the active FCI node. CLuster IP can be on node 1 and FCI IP can be on node2.